# WebGrid Helper pagination not working with .NET 4.5 MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have upgraded an mvc3 project to mvc4 project and I have changed the target framework from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 (I don't know if it's important to say).

Now, everywhere I use a webgrid helper, pagination is completely broken.
Indeed, update request is sent 4 times and the element with "displayClient" as Id is totally removed from html document.

This is few lines of my source code:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateCallback: "UpdateWebGridClient", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "displayClient", rowsPerPage: Model.RowPerPageClientId);
    grid.Bind(Model.ClientList, rowCount: Model.ClientNumber, autoSortAndPage: false);
    @grid.GetHtml(
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid", @class = "clientTable" },
        rowStyle: "odd",
        alternatingRowStyle: "even",
        footerStyle: "footerWebGrid",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        numericLinksCount: 10,
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Id", SUResources.Admin.ClientRef, style: "ref"),
            grid.Column("FullName", SUResources.Admin.ClientFullName, style: "name"),
            grid.Column("Town", SUResources.Admin.ClientTown, style: "town"),
            grid.Column("Country", SUResources.Admin.ClientCountry, style: "country"),
            grid.Column("Email", SUResources.Admin.ClientEmail, style: "email"),
            grid.Column("PurchasedPicture", SUResources.Admin.ClientPurchasedPicture, style: "purchasedPicture"),
            grid.Column("Ca", SUResources.Admin.ClientRevenue, style: "ca"),
            grid.Column(
                style: "first-icon icons",
                format: (item) => Ajax.ActionLink(
                    " ",
                    "ClientInformation",
                    new { clientId = item.Id },
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "Get",
                        UpdateTargetId = "showClientInformation",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        @class = "record"
                    }
                )
            ),
            grid.Column(
                style: "icons",
                format:
                @<text>
                    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "SendMail", new { CustomerId = item.Id }, new { @class = "green-mail" })
                </text>
            ),
            grid.Column(
                style: "icons",
                format:
                @<text>
                    @if (item.StatusId == (short)Shootus.Domain.EnumTypes.CustomerState.Active)
                    {
                        <a onclick="ChangeCustomerStatus(this);" data-customer-id="@item.Id"> <img alt="" title="@SUResources.Admin.ClientEditionActiveUser" src="/Areas/Admin/Content/Images/Icons/ico-client-active-account.png"/></a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    string CustomerCurrentStatus = SUResources.Admin.ClientEditionBannedUser;

                    CustomerCurrentStatus = (item.StatusId == (short)Shootus.Domain.EnumTypes.CustomerState.NotValidated) ? SUResources.Admin.ClientEditionEmailNotValidatedUser : CustomerCurrentStatus;
                    CustomerCurrentStatus = (item.StatusId == (short)Shootus.Domain.EnumTypes.CustomerState.TurnedOff) ? SUResources.Admin.ClientEditionUnactiveUser : CustomerCurrentStatus;
                    <a onclick="ChangeCustomerStatus(this);" data-photographer-id="@item.Id"> <img alt="" title="@CustomerCurrentStatus" src="/Areas/Admin/Content/Images/Icons/ico-client-inactive-account.png"/></a>
                    }
                </text>
            ),
            grid.Column(
                style: "icons",
                format: @<text>
                    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { Id = item.Id }, new { @class = "delete" })
                </text>
            )
        )
    );
}
<div class="dot-line">
</div>
<div class="pager client-line-pager">
    @grid.Pager()
</div>
```

Default pager in the webgrid is hidden with css property display.

I saw in the generated html that there is some new attributes like data-swhgajax, data-swhgcallback on the table and on the generated code for the pager: data-swhgcontainer, data-swhglnk,...

I use jQuery.ajaxPrefilter for handling some extra data from an external form in the page.

Is there someone have the same problem and did he have solved it ? Ideas about the origin of this problem ?

Thank you for taking the time to read this post and I hope somebody can help me :-(

Comment: I have found out why the html element was cleared after reading javascript code for the webgrid. It's beacause the updateContainerId must be the wrapper element's id of content the server returns for the ajax request. However, there is 3/4 times the same request for the update and I'm still looking for reasons of this behaviour :-/

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with a similar problem.

In my case, I was refreshing the webgrid content after an AJAX post call. And for each time the webgrid was refreshed one more get request was sent when clicking in the header links.
I was unable to find why.

I ended by "ajaxifying" the sorting of the grid:

```
$("thead tr a").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $.get($(this).attr('href'), function (data) { $('#idGrid').html(data) }) })
```

and also the pager:

```
$("tfoot tr a").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $.get($(this).attr('href'), function (data) { $('#Grid').html(data) }) })
```

I withdraw the ajaxUpdateContainerId webgrid parameter. And modify my controller returning only a partial view containing the webgrid is there is an ajax call:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest(){}
```

I do not know if this will be of use for anyone...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues after upgrading my project, which makes heavy use of WebGrid, from MVC3 to MVC4. I managed to fix the issues for my project so the solution may the same/similar

Pagination/Sorting not working - I had added a jQuery event handler that showed an ajax spinner to the grids and had to change e.g.

```
$("#my-grid a").click(function () { blockGrid($("#my-grid-div")); });
```

to

```
$("#my-grid a").click(function () { blockGrid($("#my-grid-div")); return true; });
```

i.e. return true after handling the click and this fixed the paging/sorting

Links submitting more than once - The new grid by default makes all links inside of it ajax enabled, which means that if you also use a confirmation dialog it will get submitted anyway and then submitted again if you select OK. In my case I had to change

```
myGrid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(Strings.Remove, "removemember", new { id = ViewBag.GroupId, uid = item.Id }, new { onclick = "return confirmDialog(this, 'Remove Member?', 'Remove Member?')", rel = "remove" }))))
```

to

```
myGrid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(Strings.Remove, "removemember", new { id = ViewBag.GroupId, uid = item.Id }, new { data_ajax = "false", onclick = "return confirmDialog(this, 'Remove Member?', 'Remove Member?')", rel = "remove" }))))
```

i.e. add `data_ajax = "false"`